# Почему не работает doctrine с базой?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

Делаю всё на openserver.

```
# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1/openserver/phpmyadmin
    database_port: null
    database_name: symfony
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: null
    mailer_password: null
    secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

Дальше пишу

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

И выводит ошибки

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 103:

  An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: ���� ���� ��������
  ��.


In PDOConnection.php line 47:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: ���� ���� ����������.


In PDOConnection.php line 43:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: ���� ���� ����������.


In PDOConnection.php line 43:

  PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: ���� ���� ����������.


doctrine:database:create [--shard SHARD] [--connection [CONNECTION]] [--if-not-exists] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема здесь:

```
database_host: 127.0.0.1/openserver/phpmyadmin
database_port: null
database_name: symfony
database_user: root
database_password: null
```

Host ведет на страницу phpmyadmin, а не хост базы данных (подозреваю, что БД у Вас находится на хосте `localhost`).
Порт БД не может быть `null` - укажите реальный порт БД (MySQL - 3306, PostgreSQL - 5432, по умолчанию).